# ant check is copy file succeeded

Tags: ant

I have the following ant script that copies a file to DIR A if the file is different:

```
<copy todir="<DIR A>" verbose="true" preservelastmodified="true">
   <fileset file="< file A">
      <different targetdir="<DIR A>" ignorefiletimes="true"/>
   </fileset>
</copy>
```

What I need to accomplish is to "check" if the copy happened in order to do "something else" as well.

Comment: If the copy failed for some reason, wouldn't the rest of the build fail anyway?  Why test a built-in, known-to-work function?

Comment: I said "happened" not "failed". The copy may not happen because the comparison is not satisfied. So no File A is copied to DIR A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a test before the copy to see if the files are different. Then run a test after the copy to see if the files are the same.

The `<condition>` task's [`<filesmatch>` condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#filesmatch) detects whether two files have identical content.

Here's some code:

```
<project name="ant-copy-changed-file-test" default="run">

    <target name="run" depends="-copy,-post-copy"/>

    <target name="-copy">
        <condition property="copy-should-happen">
            <not>
                <filesmatch file1="${file_A}" file2="${dir_A}/file_A"/>
            </not>
        </condition>

        <copy todir="${dir_A}" verbose="true" preservelastmodified="true">
           <fileset file="${file_A}">
              <different targetdir="${dir_A}" ignorefiletimes="true"/>
           </fileset>
        </copy>

        <condition property="copy-happened">
            <and>
                <isset property="copy-should-happen"/>
                <filesmatch file1="${file_A}" file2="${dir_A}/file_A"/>
            </and>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="-post-copy" if="copy-happened">
        <echo>Copy happened!</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```